# Does python have any direct approach to compare two .txt files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two .text files say `Sample2.txt` and `Sample1.txt`. Can these be compared programmatically if they are the same or not?

Comment: Can't you just go through line by line and check?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could just do it the cheat way

```
open("myfile.txt").read() == open("myotherfile.txt").read()
```

But that isn't the best way, probably a better way is to use [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

```
import difflib
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, file1.read(), file2.read())
```

Comment: what would it return if same? any Boolean values?

Comment: I don't know why I am getting down vote.Whereas people getting nice thought or technique by you from my post.So if you think that I can get +1 vote,Can you Up please?

Answer (score 10):

Use [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) from the standard library.

See this [example](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/difflib/index.html) use (copied from Doug Hellmann's PyMOTW)

```
import difflib

d = difflib.Differ()
diff = d.compare(text1_lines, text2_lines)
print '\n'.join(diff)
```

I spared you the output -- you better read for yourself under the provided link above.

Comment: Do i need to install any package for the same, like needed `easy_install difflib`?

Comment: Why don't you try it and tell us?

Comment: @VBSlover: "from the standard library"

Comment: `+1` for yor information sharing! both @JakobBowyer and @theodros

Comment: @theodros why used `join()` at last?

Comment: @theodros can you help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195478/downloading-files-from-filetype-fields

Comment: I'd like to help you -- it's just that I don't see any problem? I can not read for you the documentation provided under the links above. `'\n'.join(diff)` is used because the `diff`-object is a generator that gives you individual lines from the diff-output and you would to see them line by line and not all on one line, right.