# downloading files from Filetype fields?

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a way to download files from different pages and get them stored under a particular folder in a local machine. I am using Python 2.7

See the field below:

[image: Filetypefield]

**EDIT**

*here is the html content:*

```
<input type="hidden" name="supplier.orgProfiles(1152444).location.locationPurposes().extendedAttributes(Upload_RFI_Form).value.filename" value="Screenshot.docx">

<a style="display:inline; position:relative;" href="

                                      /aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=8120070&cs=LU31NT9us5P9Pvkb1BrtdwaCrEraskiCJcY6E2ucP5s.xyz">
                                Screenshot.docx
                             </a>
```

***One Possiblity I just tried:*** with the html content if add say `https://xyz.test.com` and construct the URL like as below

https://xyz.test.com/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=8120070&cs=LU31NT9us5P9Pvkb1BrtdwaCrEraskiCJcY6E2ucP5s.xyz

and place that URL on to the browser and hit `Enter` giving me a chance to download the file as screenshot mentioned. But now can we find such `aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=8120070&cs=LU31NT9us5P9Pvkb1BrtdwaCrEraskiCJcY6E2ucP5s.xyz` values how many it is present there?

**CODE** *what I tried till now*

Only pain how to download that file. using scripts constructed URL:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', {"style": "display:inline; position:relative;"}, href=True):
    href = a['href'].strip()
    href = "https://xyz.test.com/" + href
print(href)
```

Please help me here!

Let me know if you people need any more information from me, I am happy to share that to you people.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by different pages ? where are these pages being rendered from ?

Comment: @Amyth I am using 3rd party `URL`. I am using `selenium` to navigate from page to page in the web,to search any downloadable files are there,If found then download them into a particular folder. I have 10000 files like this to download.

Comment: could you post the full html ?

Comment: This is the html which contains the download link onyl... thus i have given that much only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JohnZwinck suggested you can use `urllib.urlretrieve` and use the `re` module to create a list of links on a given page and download each file. Below is an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
This script would scrape and download files using the anchor links.
"""


#Imports

import os, re, sys
import urllib, urllib2

#Config
base_url = "http://www.google.com/"
destination_directory = "downloads"


def _usage():
    """
    This method simply prints out the Usage information.
    """

    print "USAGE: %s <url>" %sys.argv[0]


def _create_url_list(url):
    """
    This method would create a list of downloads, using the anchor links
    found on the URL passed.
    """

    raw_data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    raw_list = re.findall('<a style="display:inline; position:relative;" href="(.+?)"', raw_data)
    url_list = [base_url + x for x in raw_list]
    return url_list


def _get_file_name(url):
    """
    This method will return the filename extracted from a passed URL
    """

    parts = url.split('/')
    return parts[len(parts) - 1]


def _download_file(url, filename):
    """
    Given a URL and a filename, this method will save a file locally to the»
    destination_directory path.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(destination_directory):
        print 'Directory [%s] does not exist, Creating directory...' % destination_directory
        os.makedirs(destination_directory)
    try:
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(destination_directory, filename))
        print 'Downloading File [%s]' % (filename)
    except:
        print 'Error Downloading File [%s]' % (filename)


def _download_all(main_url):
    """
    Given a URL list, this method will download each file in the destination
    directory.
    """

    url_list = _create_url_list(main_url)
    for url in url_list:
        _download_file(url, _get_file_name(url))


def main(argv):
    """
    This is the script's launcher method.
    """

    if len(argv) != 1:
        _usage()
        sys.exit(1)
    _download_all(sys.argv[1])
    print 'Finished Downloading.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

You can Change the `base_url` and the `destination_directory` according to your needs and save the script as `download.py`. Then from the terminal use it like

```
python download.py http://www.example.com/?page=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir... I have seen your 4 C's... the only `C` for me is cgrt. :) why you used `urllib`, `urllib2` both?

Comment: because accourding to http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html,  urllib.urlopen has been replaced by urllib2.urlopen in python 3. So just to make sure the script works with p3 as well.

Comment: `+1` for taking care of my confusions. `Delhi` helps `Mumbai` :) :)

Comment: The way you wrote the code,I really `fida` on it,perfect comments,nice design... really you proved `coding` is your `pation`.`U deserves 4C`

Answer (score 1):

We can't know what service you got that first image from, but we'll assume it's on a website of some kind--probably one internal to your company.

The easiest things you can try are to use [urllib.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) to "get" the file based on its URL.  You may be able to do this if you can right-click the link on that page, copy the URL, and paste it into your code.

However, that may not work, for example if there is complex authentication required before accessing that page.  You might need to write Python code that actually does the login (as if the user were controlling it, typing a password).  If you get that far, you should post that as a separate question.

Comment: Yes I can log in to the page by using `Selenium web-driver`. Only the stuck is how to prompt such handle and download such files.

Comment: You don't need to "use" the prompt--that's a feature of the browser when used by humans.  You're automating this stuff, and the prompt should not be used, I wouldn't think.  Maybe your use of Selenium WebDriver is actually hindering you--try my approach using urllib and see if that's easier.  If there's no authentication, it certainly should be.

Comment: `urllib.urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])¶` here I can give only the URL, but how the rest values. as they all are dynamic in nature. Files to be downloaded from fields which are present in that page. that page contains different types of fields along with such file type fields.

Comment: Oh, well, you could use BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to scrape the page and get the file list.  And I don't see why you need to know the file type--it seems to be implied by the extension anyway, so isn't needed once you've downloaded the file.

Comment: `+1` for the suggestions, I am already using the `BS4` to extract the webpage values. But download files how possible? please guide. If you want I can give you the `HTML` content of the page!

Comment: Perhaps you should now post a new question with your BeautifulSoup code if you're having trouble.