# Python Creating Dictionary from excel data

Tags: python, xlrd

I want to create a dictionary from the values, i get from excel cells, 
My code is below,

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(2)   
for i in range(138):
    cell_value_class = sh.cell(i,2).value
    cell_value_id = sh.cell(i,0).value
```

and I want to create a dictionary, like below, that consists of the values coming from the excel cells;

```
{'class1': 1, 'class2': 3, 'class3': 4, 'classN':N}
```

Any idea on how I can create this dictionary?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
d = {}
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(2)   
for i in range(138):
    cell_value_class = sh.cell(i,2).value
    cell_value_id = sh.cell(i,0).value
    d[cell_value_class] = cell_value_id
```

Comment: Is `d` a dictionary object or any array?

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU - according to `d = {}`, it is a dictionary.

Comment: `+1` to you for the concept.

Comment: @eumiro Can you look into this post [file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195478/downloading-files-from-filetype-fields)

Answer (score 53):

or you can try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)

```
from pandas import *
xls = ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
print df.to_dict()
```

Comment: I don't know why but I also frequently just type "_print ..._" without brackets. And it happens to me only in python. Maybe it because some things like _if_ and _for_ do not have any brackets. I never forget brackets by other functions

Answer (score 18):

This script allows you to transform an excel data table to a list of dictionaries:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls', on_demand = True)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = [] # The row where we stock the name of the column
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    first_row.append( worksheet.cell_value(0,col) )
# transform the workbook to a list of dictionaries
data =[]
for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    elm = {}
    for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
        elm[first_row[col]]=worksheet.cell_value(row,col)
    data.append(elm)
print data
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Pandas to do this. Import pandas and Read the excel as a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'path_for_your_input_excel_sheet'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, encoding='utf-16')
```

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` to convert a pandas dataframe to a dictionary. [Find the documentation for the same here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict)

```
df.to_dict()
```

This would give you a dictionary of the excel sheet you read.

Generic Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2],'col2': [0.5, 0.75]},index=['a', 'b'])
```

`>>> df`

`col1  col2
a     1   0.50
b     2   0.75`

`>>> df.to_dict()`

`{'col1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'col2': {'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.75}}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert your Excel data into a list of dictionaries in python using pandas,
Best way to do that:

```
excel_file_path = 'Path to your Excel file'
excel_records = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)
excel_records_df = excel_records.loc[:, ~excel_records.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
records_list_of_dict=excel_records_df.to_dict(orient='record')
Print(records_list_of_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(2)   
lookup = dict(zip(sh.col_values(2, 0, 138), sh.col_values(0, 0, 138)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a PyPI package for that: https://pypi.org/project/sheet2dict/
It is parsing excel and csv files and returning it as an array of dictionaries.
Each row is represented as a dictionary in the array.

Like this way :

```
Python 3.9.0 (default, Dec  6 2020, 18:02:34)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

# Import the library
>>> from sheet2dict import Worksheet

# Create an object
>>> ws = Worksheet()

# return converted rows as dictionaries in the array 
>>> ws.xlsx_to_dict(path='Book1.xlsx')
[
    {'#': '1', 'question': 'Notifications Enabled', 'answer': 'True'}, 
    {'#': '2', 'question': 'Updated', 'answer': 'False'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can convert it to csv this is very suitable.

```
import dataconverters.commas as commas
filename = 'test.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
      records, metadata = commas.parse(f)
      for row in records:
            print 'this is row in dictionary:'+row
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use, openpyxl below code might help:

```
import openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("ExcelDemo.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active
first_row = [] # The row where we stock the name of the column
for col in range(1, sheet.max_column+1):
    first_row.append(sheet.cell(row=1, column=col).value)
data =[]
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
    elm = {}
    for col in range(1, sheet.max_column+1):
        elm[first_row[col-1]]=sheet.cell(row=row,column=col).value
    data.append(elm)
print (data)
```

credit to: [Python Creating Dictionary from excel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196013/python-creating-dictionary-from-excel-data/35034935#35034935)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of ways but this is the most effective way I found:

```py
import pyexcel as p

def read_records():
    records = p.get_records(file_name="File")
    products = [row for row in records]
    return products
```