# Turn multiple lists into one list in python

Tags: python, list, merge

I have a spreadsheet with data which I have imported into python using the following code;

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xls')

sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    print sh.row_values(rownum)
```

This prints out each row of the spreadsheet; eg.

```
[13.0, 2.0, 92.0, 83.0]
[10.0, 8.0, 80.0, 78.0]
[7.0, 4.0, 121.0, 60.0]
```

How do I grab these separate lists and merge them into one list that would look like;

```
test = [[13.0, 2.0, 92.0, 83.0], [10.0, 8.0, 80.0, 78.0], [7.0, 4.0, 121.0, 60.0]]
```

Thanks,

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis it's not a valid duplicate.

Comment: Also highly related [What does "list comprehension" in Python mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
test = [sh.row_values(rownum) for rownum in range(sh.nrows)]
```

Comment: I know the OP doesn't ask for this, per se, but I like your answer and I think you could add this bit to it: this can be expanded slightly so as to [append the names of each column to the row values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23568655/5209610): `for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): test = [ {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value for col_index in range(sh.ncols)} for row_index in range(sh.nrows) ]` it might be helpful for someone viewing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line before the loop:

```
final = []
```

Then instead of print change the line to:

```
final.append(sh.row_values(rownum))
```

It should do what you ask for.