# Python Excel Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, excel, package, sentiment-analysis

This is my first time posting on a forum regarding coding.

I'm an inexperienced Python user and am currently tackling a project regarding Sentiment Analysis of Feedbacks which are stored in an excel file.

I would like to ask what are the appropriate/best packages to be used to do Sentiment Analysis on an excel file using Python.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question elicits opinions and doesn't really fit this forum.

However NLTK seems to be the main library for language processing and sentiment analysis in Python.
http://www.nltk.org/

Textblob is another that's arguably simpler than NLTK.
http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/

To process excel files you can use the XLRD library
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

There are many resources with examples on using XLRD. Here's a good one for instance: [XLRD/Python: Reading Excel file into dict with for-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568409/xlrd-python-reading-excel-file-into-dict-with-for-loops)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Sorry that I put it on the wrong forums but I genuinely needed help.

Comment: Sure no problem.