# How do you upload a .py file into mongodb through pymongo

Tags: python, excel, mongodb, pymongo

I have a lot of data from an excel sheet and I used python to read that data with xlrd and am now outputting all of that data from python. My question is, how do I take that data that I am outputting through python, and upload it on MongoDB. I understand that pymongo must be used, but am not quite sure how to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you've read the tutorials but still don't get it...

You'll need to convert your xlrd data into a list of dictionaries, one dictionary for each row in your spreadsheet.  Here's a clue: [Python Creating Dictionary from excel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196013/python-creating-dictionary-from-excel-data)

Once you have the list of dictionaries/rows, make sure you have MongoDB running on your machine, then:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient().mydb  # create a database called 'mydb'
for row_dict in list_of_rows:
    db.rows.save(row_dict)  # saves each row in collection called "rows"
```