# Get info from Json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to get a members info from json file. I converted excel list to json file.

[image]

So for example: when we type `?Apple` in discord channel it should Vlookup `A Row` and `B Row` and `C Row` for data.

Bot will reply like this.

[image]

again when we type `?Dog` in discord channel.

Bot will reply like this.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by reply but you can use `openpyxl` or `xlswriter`. Look these up, pretty straight forward.

Comment: It's possible, but it seems unnecessary.  Why not just use a dictionary, or a json file?

Comment: Look at some of the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196013/python-creating-dictionary-from-excel-data).  I think your best bet is to just read the contents of the excel file into a local dictionary.  Unless your excel file is *very* large, this will be fine.

Comment: 2000 rows is not too large to read in the excel file into a dictionary, or look at creating a `dataframe`, ***Pandas*** is a good option. If you require a more robust answer, please update question with a clear example and `code trials` to work from.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  I converted excel file to json file now i can i get a particular row info about a member when we type command in discord server. I searched full google i not got any examples.