# I want import data from excel, put it in a list of dictionarys in python, then overwrite the data in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

for now I hae this: (I'm skipping the lines that are useless here)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

archivo = "./inventario.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(archivo)
ws = wb.active

def saveInventary(cantidad, producto, precio):
    inventario.append({'cantidad' : cantidad , 'producto' : producto , 'precio' : precio })
```

## The inside of this is only to work

```
inventario = [{'cantidad': 2,
                'producto' : "tornillo", 
                'precio' : 2,
                  }] 

contador = 1
qty = ws["A" + str(contador)].value 
pdct = ws["B" + str(contador)].value
price = ws["C" + str(contador)].value
```

## Those are the lines that don't worok as I want

```
inventario2 = [qty, pdct, price]

for row in inventario2:
    saveInventary(qty, pdct, price)
    contador = contador + 1 
    
print (inventario)
wb.save(archivo)
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196013/python-creating-dictionary-from-excel-data

Comment: Don't do this `qty = ws["A" + str(contador)].value ` do this `qty = ws.cell(column=1, row=contador)`. Even better `for row in ws.iter_rows(max_col=3)`

Comment: @CharlieClark I dont get it, i dont understand what to do with the "even better option" can u help a little bit more? what do I put under the for row in ws.iter_rows(max_col=3) to add it to my existent dicctionary?

Comment: @CharlieClark I did this, u was talking about this `contador = 1
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1,
                        max_col=3):
                        

    
    qty = ws.cell(column=1, row=contador).value
    pdct = ws.cell(column=2, row=contador).value
    price =ws.cell(column=3, row=contador).value


    saveInventary(qty, pdct, price)
    contador = contador + 1`

Comment: Update the question with your code.